# Laravel and Apple Wallet - the webServiceURL isn't getting called or invoked by the wallet application

Tags: php, laravel, apple-wallet

Let me give some context:
I'm working on a project where there are several stores, each store defines his own offers based on (Buy X - Get Y) model, for example: Buy 6 coffee cups and get 2 for free, and a QR code is generated for this offer

The user isn't required to download any application, he just scan the QR code which generates a pass of type storeCard for him, and he will use the wallet application on his iPhone device to add this pass

This whole implementation is being done using Laravel framework and using this package https://github.com/thenextweb/passgenerator (`thenextweb/passgenerator`) to implement the functionality of generating passes

As mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html
We need to define a `webServiceURL`, i've defined it in my code that looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\Offer;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Thenextweb\Definitions\Coupon;
use Thenextweb\PassGenerator;

class PassService
{
    public function generate(
        int          $offer_id,
        string       $description,
        string|array $assets = NULL
    ) {
        // dd(url("item.png"));
        $offer = Offer::findOrFail($offer_id);
        $facility = $offer->facility;

        $pass = new PassGenerator();
        $serial = Str::uuid();

        // $auxiliaryFields = [];

        // for ($i = 0; $i < $offer->info->purchased_items_count; $i++) {
        //     $temp = [
        //         "key" => "item",
        //         "label" => "Offer Item",
        //         "value" => "Test",
        //         // "icon" => url("item.png")
        //         "icon" => [
        //             "data" => base64_encode(file_get_contents(public_path("item.png"))),
        //             "mime" => "image/png",
        //             "filename" => "item.png"
        //         ]
        //     ];
        //     $auxiliaryFields[] = $temp;
        // }

        $pass_definition = [
            "organizationName" => $facility->name,
            "backgroundColor" => "rgb(212, 212, 212)",
            "foregroundColor" => "rgb(99, 99, 99)",
            "logoText" => $description,
            "locations" => [
                (object)[
                    "altitude" => 50,
                    "latitude" => 37.33211150000000344562067766673862934112548828125,
                    "longitude" => -122.0307624000000004116373020224273204803466796875,
                    "relevantText" => "This is a test"
                ]
            ],
            "barcode" => [

                "message" => $description,
                "format" => "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
                "messageEncoding" => "utf-8",
            ],
            "storeCard" => [
                "headerFields" => [
                    [
                        "key" => "offer_name",
                        "label" => "Offer Name",
                        "value" => $offer->name
                    ]
                ],
                "primaryFields" => [
                    [
                        "key" => "offer_type",
                        "label" => "Offer Type",
                        "value" => Str::replace("_", " ", $offer->offer_type),
                    ],
                ],
                "backFields" => [
                    [
                        "key" => "purchased_items_count",
                        "label" => "Purchased Items Count",
                        "value" => $offer->info->purchased_items_count,
                    ],
                    [
                        "key" => "offer_items_count",
                        "label" => "Offer Items Count",
                        "value" => $offer->info->offer_items_count,
                    ],
                ],
                // "auxiliaryFields" => $auxiliaryFields,
            ],
            "authenticationToken" => "0123456789ABCDEF",
            "webServiceURL" => url("offers/verify") . "/", //route('offers.verify'),
            "serialNumber" => $serial,
            "formatVersion" => 1,
            "description" => $description,
            "passTypeIdentifier" => "pass.ixcoders.alwalaa",
            "teamIdentifier" => "J2UMUTGYQC",
        ];

        // dd($pass_definition);
        $pass->setPassDefinition($pass_definition);

        if (!is_null($assets)) {
            if (is_array($assets)) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($assets); $i++) {
                    $asset = $assets[$i];
                    $pass->addAsset($asset);
                }
            } else {
                $pass->addAsset($assets);
            }
        }

        return $pass->create();
    }
}
```

However, the `webServiceURL` isn't being called eventhough it's defined.

I've even created a middleware that logs all requests, and tried to see if this URL was being called, but it seems not.

The URL has SSL installed.